# How can i change the width of the scrollbar track

Tags: html, css

im trying to change the width of the scrollbar track, follwing a design, but i cant figure how the scrollbar is the thing bellow the carousel, ty.

css

```
.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background: gray;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

design

[image]

Comment: I think we need to see the full code of the slider (html, css and javascript) to see what is happening. Normally the scrollbar track takes the width of the scrollable element, minus the margin on the scrollbar track. Which in this case is the element with the `carousel` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add left/right margins to the horizontal track.

```
.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    margin-inline:100px;
}
```

EG:

```css
.carousel {
  display:flex;
  overflow:auto;
  column-gap:10px;
  width:320px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carousel div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  min-width:100px; aspect-ratio:1;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:20%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* ⬆ for demo / for you ⬇ */

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 4px;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
  margin-inline:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked, thanks, i have to look how to make it for all the browsers

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak around with the `margin`; for example, like so:

```
.carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
    margin: 140px; 
  }
```

Also, for responsiveness we have to lower them at each media screen width. For example, like so:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
  .carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
        margin: 200px; 
      }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
        margin: 150px; 
      }
}
@media (max-width: 360px){
  .carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal {
        margin: 100px; 
      }
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit bug prone since margins can collapse on their selves - when used in responsive layout. Also there's no need to use `-left` and `-right`.